# Unable to use Oracle Data Access after publishing to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, wcf, azure

I installed 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x6464-bit on my machine. and used this to connect to a remote oracle db. this worked well when I deployed to a normal IIS. But when is published to azure as an Azure cloud service (my project is a WCF service). I get the following error 
      System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll'

Now I have no idea why this is happening. This is the  code I'm using to  connect to db

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=Usr;Password=*****;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));";
con.Open();
OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand();
string comandtext = "Select * from COR_EMPL_MASTER where EMPL_CODE='" + u.EMPL_EMPL_Code + "'";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comandtext, con);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fixed it

Hey use this link to http://alderprogs.blogspot.com/2009/04/deploying-odpnet-with-oracle-instant.html. Firstly use the Xcopy version of the drivers downloaded from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html add reference to Oracle.dataaccess.dll from this after which right click on it and select properties and in the properties set "local copy=true"

then what you have to do is right-click on the project select "Add Existing Item". Add all the required dlls like oci.dll,OraOps12.dll etc. Now in the properties of these of these dlls set "Copy to output directory = Copy if Newer" and publish to azure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no OraOps12.dll file on azure.

You can throw OraOps12.dll into /Bin folder in your project and add Reference for it by virsual studio. After that you can publish your project to Azure cloud service.

Comment: where would i get this dll from

Comment: You can go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: still need to add Reference for the OraOps12.dll by virsual studio, not just throw it into bin folder. I will update my answer

Comment: already tried that. vs doesnt allow me to add reference to this dll

Comment: any error message? normally no any issue when you reference a dll in vs